# order records by depth AND sibling order

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, singly-linked-list, recursive-query

I have a tree structure I want to order. Vertically and horizontally.

From SQLite doc I got the ordering by depth :

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  under_alice(name,level) AS (
    VALUES('Alice',0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT org.name, under_alice.level+1
      FROM org JOIN under_alice ON org.boss=under_alice.name
     ORDER BY 2 DESC
  )
SELECT substr('..........',1,level*3) || name FROM under_alice;
```

Which gives:

```
Alice
...Bob
......Dave
......Emma
...Cindy
......Fred
......Gail
```

In that request the ordering is only on the level. So the order of siblings (Bob & Cindy, Dave & Emma, Fred & Gail) is not constrained (ie it is insert order).

But I also need to order siblings. So I think about a sibling column with the id of the next sibling (like in a linked list).

The table would be `table org (name text, boss name, sibling name)`

The data :

```
'Alice', null, null
'Cindy', 'Alice', 'Bob'
'Bob', 'Alice', null
'Dave', 'Bob', 'Emma'
'Emma', 'Bob', null
'Gail', 'Cindy', 'Fred'
'Fred', 'Cindy', null
```

And the result would then be:

```
Alice
...Cindy
......Gail
......Fred
...Bob
......Dave
......Emma
```

How can I integrate that into the recursive request ?

Comment: Not sure what you want. `order by` primarily applies to the outermost query though.

Comment: I want to order inside the same level, eg Dave & Emma, Fred & Gail, Bob & Cindy

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you *want*.  Also explain how the siblings should be ordered, and why the results you are getting don't meet your needs.

Comment: Simon, the table you are suggesting is a  **very bad idea**!!! Since (I assume) the contents is prone to change, imagine the complexity of the mechanism to implement changes. For instance, imagine that you want to insert `Gerard` between `Gail` and `Fred`. You would need to update two records in addition to the insertion of the new one.

Comment: @FDavidov What other way would you use then ? (also only Gail would need updating, not Fred)

Comment: Well, I have a similar situation in one of my projects in which there is a hierarchical structure. Each entry contains an ID, Parent-ID and node name. That is enough to build a properly sorted list. Since you got your answer (from CL.) I see no need to go into details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the sibling specification into a format usable for ORDER BY, use another recursive CTE to count the siblings under the same boss. Because there is nothing that identifies the first sibling, the search is easier backwards:

```
WITH RECURSIVE OrderedOrg(Name, Boss, SiblingOrder) AS (
  SELECT Name, Boss, 0
  FROM org
  WHERE Sibling IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT org.Name, org.Boss, OrderedOrg.SiblingOrder + 1
  FROM org
  JOIN OrderedOrg ON org.Boss    = OrderedOrg.Boss
                 AND org.Sibling = OrderedOrg.Name
),
under_alice(...) AS (
  ...
  SELECT ...
  FROM ... OrderedOrg ...
  ...
  ORDER BY level DESC, SiblingOrder DESC
)
SELECT ...
```

Comment: Excellent thank you very much ! I didn't thought about doing the sibling request backwards !

Comment: I continued with the request and tried to add a left join and a group_concat on the data joined ... but that requires to add a group by ... and the group by destroys the order. Would you have an answer for that issue ? (I can't do the group_concat inside the with statement because SQLITE doesn't support it) All I can think of is to put the group_concat in a seperate view.

Comment: Sounds like a new question.